# Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am following a tutorial on building a social media app using django.
I have this bug that has kept me stuck for days despite doing exactly as the tutorial goes.
Whenever i try to open the settings page of my profile, I get a doesNotExist error.

the error seems to be coming from here "    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) "
This the views for my settings page

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):
    # Check if logged in user has profile, if not redirect to create profile
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'user_profile': user_profile})
```

Sometimes I get an error about the profile_img not being found. Although i couldn't get it to repeat itself at the time of asking for help here. But when I commented out the profile_img line in my modles.py, the error changed back to 'profile not matching query'

This my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', default='blank_profile_image.jpeg')
```

However, removing the link to to my modles.py seems to make the settings page accessible.

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):
    # Check if logged in user has profile, if not redirect to create profile
    #user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'core/settings.html', )
```

This is my files directory structure
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xuym.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is causing because you do not have the data for current user in the `Profile` model. The workaround here should be checking if data exists or do something else, Example -

```py
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):
    # Check if logged in user has profile, if not redirect to create profile
    user_profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if user_profile.exists()
        return render(request, 'settings.html', {'user_profile': user_profile[0]})
    else:
        return redirect("/") # or wherever you want to
```

Answer (score 0):

Does a profile object exist for the user you're logged in as?

You can quicky debug it by doing:

```py
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):
    print('User Profile QS:', Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    # Check if logged in user has profile, if not redirect to create profile
    # user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'core/settings.html', )
```

Look at the terminal output and if it's empty, and it'll most likely be, just create one and it should work.

---

Per your comment `Check if logged in user has profile, if not redirect to create profile`
It might be better to refactor the view to be more like:

```py
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):
    # Check if logged in user has profile, if not redirect to create profile
    user_profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

    if user_profile is None:
      from django.shortcuts import redirect
      return redirect('/my_redirect_url/')

    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'user_profile': user_profile})
```

Comment: I did the quick debug and I got a response for the profile query. Which I am guessing, means that the profile object exists for the user.
Any idea what else could be the problem?

Comment: The quick debug wouldn't have crashed, because it was a filter.
if the profile **didn't** exist it would look like this: `User Profile QS: <QuerySet []>`
if it **did** it would look like this: `User Profile QS: <QuerySet [<Profile Object (1)>]>`

...If the profile **does** exist, this error makes no sense, I'd have no idea which direction to point you towards